# How to handle different prepositions in internationalization?

Tags: internationalization

I'm currently working on an application which I plan translate in the future (right now it's only in English).

I would like to have a resource file for each language and just put the appropriate string where needed. I don't know how to solve the following problem:

Example (English -> French):

- It's raining in Paris -> Il pleut à Paris.
- It's raining in Massachusetts -> Il pleut au Massachusetts.

(Sorry if the sentences in French are wrong, I translated them using Google Translator. I only want them to help me explain my problem.)

The thing is, the sentences in French have different prepositions depending on where it is raining. Is there any best practice regarding this? I can't just pull "It's raining in" from the resource file and append the location.

The project I'm working on is a web application in JavaScript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more detail, what kind of app are you making?
You can just, as you stated, pull the string up until a variable "It's raining in" or you can split the sentence to say "start of sentence" variable "end of sentence". And if in English it's not the same then just use the "start of the sentence" and leave the "end of the sentence" empty. If I understood you correctly.